# PhpStorm: Can't analyse webpack.config.js: coding assistance will ignore module resolution rules in this file

Tags: laravel, webpack, phpstorm

The error started appearing at the start up of PhpStorm after I have upgraded to 2017.3.3

Webpack.config.js is a default one from Laravel 5.5 build.

Tried to suppress it with no success. Very annoying. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: this message means that webpack evaluation has failed for some reason. please create a support ticket, attaching your idea.log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) to it.

Comment: thanks @lena. I have suppressed the error thanks to Edwin answer. So it does not disturb me anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get rid of this problem you can remove the notifications & log for the Webpack from `Settings->Apperance&Behavior->Notifications->Webpack`

Comment: Woah. Thank you bro :)

Comment: This solution ignores the problem but not solve that. is any way to solve?

Comment: maybe this can help you a little: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-webpack.html or just follow the tracker (see link for the tracker in this link https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/06/webstorm-2017-2-eap-172-2827/)

Answer (score 2):

**Common Cause:**

There's an error in the Javascript used in your Webpack config when evaluated by IntelliJ.

**But it works on the commandline?**

It may work fine from the command line but the context that IntelliJ evaluates the config is different than the command line.

**How can I tell what the Javascript error is?**

Below the `Can't analyse webpack.config.js` error message, look for `Error details:`. If it's a Javascript error, this will give you a hint of what's failing.

**Example:**

I saw the following error when I opened a project in IntelliJ

> Can't analyse webpack.config.js: coding assistance will ignore module resolution rules in this file.
>                   Possible reasons: this file is not a valid webpack configuration file or its format is not currently supported by the IDE.
>                   **Error details:  Cannot read property 'require' of undefined**

In this case, there was a plugin configuration in the `webpack.config.js` using `require.main.require`. This is fine when ran from the command line but fails in IntelliJ because of the way IntelliJ evaluates the `webpack.config.js`. When IntelliJ evaluates it, `require.main` is `undefined`.

Comment: And when I don't have _"Error details:"_?

Comment: For me, my config has a `devServer` property. When it is there, it doesn't work. If I comment it out, the aliases are recognized. Is there any clue as to how it's "analyzed" if it works using build tools but not in the IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Just an workaround. This will make some changes to your project, but you can revert everything back to its original state after if PhpStorm works fine.

STEP 1

1. Make sure your git status is clean.
2. Close your PhpStorm.
3. Remove `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`.
4. Then regenerate `package-lock.json` with `npm install`.
5. Start PhpStorm and open your project.
6. Confirm that now it works. Event log like

> Module resolution rules from webpack.config.js are now used for coding assistance.

STEP 2

1. Discard all changes with `git checkout .`.
2. Revert under `node_modules` with `npm ci`.
3. Now your project is before the workaround but with coding assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have automatic Webpack detection activated in PhpStorm, and you use a webpack.mix.js (as in legacy Laravel apps), this error pops up as well in 2023.2.3. Just switch to manual detection and select the correct file.